# Rails: increment db column if event has occurred today, create new entry if not

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an imposed limit on daily user actions in my application and I want to track how many time per day the user reaches the limit.

I've got a `Limit` model that belongs to `User`, and the limits table has two columns: `users_per_day_reached` and `events_per_day_reached`.

Limit model:

```
   id: nil,
   created_at: nil,
   updated_at: nil,
   users_per_day_reached: nil,
   events_per_day_reached: nil,
   user_id: nil
```

When a user hits the events per day limit based on their account tier, I want to increment `events_per_day_reached` counter in the database every time that happens for that date.

So, I am trying to figure out how to do something like:

```
if @user.limits.last.updated_at === Date.today
    @user.limits.last.events_per_day_reached.increment!
elsif
    @limit = Limit.new(user_id: @user.id)
    @limit.increment(:events_per_day_reached)
    @limit.save
end
```

I just don't know the most "Rails" way to write those queries.

Comment: Do you face any errors? If yes, please share the stack trace in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `updated_at` column is datetime, but is compared with date

One of the solutions will be to cast datetime to date:

```
@user.limits.last.updated_at.to_date == Date.today
```

Or (probably more elegant) there's [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#today?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-today-3F) method, which does the trick:

```
if @user.limits.last.updated_at.today?
    @user.limits.last.events_per_day_reached.increment!
else
    @limit = Limit.new(user_id: @user.id)
    @limit.increment(:events_per_day_reached)
    @limit.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, the conditional block should be

`if @user.limits.last.updated_at.to_date == Date.today
    your code.....
 else
    your code.....
 end`

`elsif` takes an argument